# Encryption querying - Do I need Shield?

Tags: encryption

We are currently using REST queries to pull data from Salesforce. We would like for some of that data to be encrypted. Is it possible to query encrypted data ? How will it be displayed in the external platform ? Do I need Shield for this functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

Shield Platform Encryption encrypts data at rest on the Salesforce server.

Classic Encryption also encrypts field data at rest, but requires a special user permission to view the field and has a wide variety of limitations, including particularly that it applies only to short custom text fields.

In neither case will the encrypted form of the data be returned in response to a query. You will either receive plaintext data or you will be unable to access the data at all if not appropriately permissioned. With Shield Encryption, access to data is permissioned through ordinary field-level security.

Note however that using Shield Encryption comes with a significant number of [trade-offs and considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_considerations_general.htm), and in particular towards your question

> You can’t include fields encrypted with the probabilistic encryption scheme in the following SOQL and SOSL clauses and functions:
>
> Aggregate functions such as MAX(), MIN(), and COUNT_DISTINCT()
>       WHERE clause
>       GROUP BY clause
>       ORDER BY clause
>
> For information about SOQL and SOSL compatibility with deterministic encryption, see Considerations for Using Deterministic Encryption in Salesforce Help.

You'll need to very carefully evaluate your queries used both on and off platform before deciding to utilize Shield Encryption and how to implement it.

Comment: So, I would like to encrypt data at rest, but allow certain employees read the fields which are encrypted. I also have external users accessing Salesforce data from an external UI which is querying Salesforce. Some of the data which will need to be displayed there will come from encrypted fields. The encrypted fields will not necessarily be part of the query (WHERE), but will just be one of the fields pulled. So, can I accomplish all of that with classic out of the box encryption - or do I need Shield for that ?

Comment: Classic Encryption only supports encryption of certain short, custom text fields. If you need more functionality than that, you need Shield. Other than Classic Encrypted Fields, you should control data access via FLS, not encryption.

Comment: Shield is about encrypting your data at rest, not controlling user-level access.

Comment: I understand this is not about user-level access. I'm not trying to control who can see the field, only who can actually read the data. In this case, I am assuming everybody has read access to the field(s), but they are encrypted so nobody can actually read the data, except the users who also have the Read Encrypted Data permission via a Permission Set. Am I right with that assessment ? If so, then I don't understand what benefit I would get from Shield, besides the ability to encrypt more field types than short text fields.

Comment: I'm afraid that is incorrect. [Read Encrypted Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&type=5) applies to Classic Encryption for Custom Fields. With that notable exception permission to see the field and permission to read the data in the field are not distinct.

Comment: This older [Knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315108&type=1&mode=1) may also shed some light.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have read both of those articles and I'm not sure what would prevent me from using the scenario I drew out. The 2nd article did pose some questions to me, but unless Classic Encryption is no longer encrypting data at rest then I think my needs may still be able to be met. From what I see in that article, the SF user with Read access to the encrypted field would now be able to read the encrypted data. If that is the case then could I accomplish my needs by just not giving users read access to the field at all ?

Comment: btw - I am using this as a reference right now : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_vs_classic_encryption.htm&type=5

Also - I'm currently testing this and I am only seeing masked data in an encrypted field. But once I give myself a Permission Set with 'View Encrypted Data' I am able to see the text.....and isn't that the proper behavior ? It seems to contradict that Knowledge Article you posted.

Comment: That is the expected behavior for Classic Encryption. It is not the behavior in Shield Platform Encryption.